# How do I share Python code to a Spyder user?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio, spyder

I develop Python 3.6 code in Visual Studio 2017, and I need to send the code to a person using Spyder.

VS uses some *.sln and *.pyproj files, which define many things like the location of the *.py files, and I guess are only used on VS, and I guess Spyder uses a different format.

Is there a straightforward way to send the solution to a spyder user?

Can Spyder import VS code?

Or can I "export" the solution into some Python standard?

I guess that probably Spyder doesn't even has the concept of a "solution", but at least may have the concept of a *.pyproj file.
Exporting that would be good enough.

I had been googling it, and found nothing.

Comment: Presumably your actual code is in a folder containing one or more .py files. What else is there about the project that needs to be sent?

Comment: The *.sln file is probably of no use for spyder, but the *.pyproj indicates which *.py file is the startup file, and which *.py files are included.

Comment: @nekomatic Also, I used a lot of python packages, and I wonder if spyder users would be able to tell what packages need to be installed. I guess that they can read all `import´ lines, but I would like to make it as easier as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To organise a collection of .py files in a way that defines which is the startup file, structure them as one or more modules in a Python [package](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages). Your users can then `import` the module(s) from your package that they want to use.

You can distribute this to people as a simple zipped folder of files, but if you want users to be able to easily install both your package and its dependencies then you could build a distribution package that they can install using the `pip` command, as set out [here](https://docs.python.org/3/distributing/index.html).

Having said that, if you have users who are using Spyder then they are probably using the Anaconda python distribution and its `conda` package manager, and the absolute best way of distributing software to them will be as a [conda package](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tutorials/build-pkgs.html).

Those last two links probably go into far more detail than you need for a simple project, but one or both of them is probably the way to go if you really want to help your users manage dependencies and updates to your package.

Apart from that, I'm not aware of any ‘project’ concept in Spyder.

One more thought, instead of ‘sending’ someone the code would it be an option to commit it to a repository on Github or similar from which they could then download it? That should preserve any folder structure and so on that you want to maintain.

Comment: I didn't checked it on Python, but VS has a direct menu to "export to git repo". Do packages allow the user to edit the code? (I can't see the code of my imported packages)

Comment: A package is just a collection of files in a specific structure, as described on the first link, so yes, a user of the package can edit the code. You can see the code of the packages you've installed as long as you know where to find it - on my Windows Anaconda installation they're in `C:\Users\<myuser>\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\<envname>` but yours will be different depending on how you've installed Python.